# Mongodb shutdown with error when mongorestore

Tags: mongodb, shutdown, mongorestore

I am restoring the data to mongodb. After the data imported, and before all indexes rebuilt, it throws some error, and shuts itself down.

Is there anyone familiar with this condition?

The error log:

> `Wed Nov 16 13:32:10 Socket recv() errno:104 Connection reset by peer 127.0.0.1:27017`
>   `Wed Nov 16 13:32:10 SocketException: remote: 127.0.0.1:27017 error: 9001 socket exception [1] server [127.0.0.1:27017]`
>   `Wed Nov 16 13:32:10 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
>   assertion: 10276 DBClientBase::findN: transport error: localhost query: { getlasterror: 1 }`

Comment: Resolved, memory issue, I freed enough memory, and the mongorestore runs well.

Comment: Good you got it solved. You can write that as an answer and then accept it.

Comment: How much memory did you have and how much memory did you allocate?